# Many shot, medium shot, few shot?

Tags: loss

While I was reading one CVPR 2020 paper, titled ***Equalization loss for long-tailed object recognition***, I cannot understand the terms "many shot", "medium shot", and "few shot". Could you give me an advice for understanding those terms?

[Click 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Xah.png)

[Click 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ6Rg.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following definition should meet these terms:

"""
...many-shot classes (classes each with
over training 100 samples), medium-shot classes (classes
each with 20∼100 training samples) and few-shot classes
(classes under 20 training samples)
"""

source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05160.pdf